# SignalR stops working after an indeterminate amount of time, on IIS6

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, signalr

We have an app with a reporting module.

When user requests a report, we are using SignalR to report the progress of the report back to the user. We do this by reporting messages to the Caller. The messages are progress snippets to indicate activity, such as "Loading data..." "Compiling..." "Decrypting..." etc. Then a formatted excel spreadsheet is sent down the wire and the user downloads.

The problem I am having is that we deploy this to production, and for an indeterminate period it is working great, then for some unknown reason (to me) it stops working. /SignalR/Hubs disappears and turns into a 404 error.

The app is a hybrid asp.net and classic asp app, and is hosted on IIS6.

We are using SignalR version v1.1.3 (recently upgraded from 0.5 to see if this fixed the issue, but it is still present). We can't upgrade to 2.x because the webserver (Windows 2003) is not supported for dotnet 4.5 and that's what the new Owin needs I think.

The only way I can get it working again is to recycle the app pool, but this is highly problematic as the app uses the session, so this logs everyone out, meaning if the reports go down, we either have to kick everyone off or wait until a maintenance window to restart the app pool.

I have tried nearly everything I can find online to remedy. Our Request Queue Limit was raised to 20000, we are using the right script tags and references etc. I can't turn on debugging because the hub cannot be found at all after a while. Extremely frustrating bug because we cannot replicate or pinpoint any problems.

So the question is has anyone experienced this, or how can I track down the cause of this issue? Also is there a better support channel for SignalR?

Any help at all will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: when "/signalr/hubs" starts returning 404, can you still access fine other resources on same server like html, images, aspx files?

Comment: Hi Gustavo, yes I can, everything works as normal, except the hubs disappears, so the users cannot get their reports.

Comment: Took a look into the Event Log?

Comment: Hi Uwe, I have just now, can't see anything obvious. Any ideas what I should be looking for?

Comment: Can't find anything in the event log, is there any other way I can trace errors in Signal R, maybe use Nlog or any ideas on how to track down?

Comment: Since you cant use .NET 4.5 SignalR is not a good option. You probably do not want to hear this, but either upgrade the servers or use  XSockets.NET (supports sockets on all platforms)